# Image not adapting to the width set

Tags: image, css

I have a section on a site that I have multiple image blocks. I have two columns with multiple rows. For some reason the margin and width are not being applied to these images. I have the following code in my media query for a `viewport` of 640px or less. Whenever you drag the corner of the page, the images do not scale in size at all. Also the left images stay in place instead of moving with the margin.

It is under the part called Site Sponsors in a `viewport` of 640px or less.

What is causing the images to not scale in `height` and `width` as well as the margin?

As you can see I have the images `width` defined in a percentage basis:

```
.b_250 img {
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
}
.b_250 iframe {
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
}
```

As well as the margin defined:

```
.sponsors {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<div id="sponsor-left">
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="PMC-spray-foam-equipment"><img src="images/Contractor Images/PMC spray foam equipment for sale.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="Green-Insulation-Technologies"><img src="images/Contractor Images/Green Insulation Technology 300x200.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="Sprayworks-Equipment-Group"><img src="images/Contractor Images/Spray foam rigs for sale a series.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sponsor-right">
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="b_250">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
/*----Second to Last Homepage Article---*/
#latestnews {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#latestnews .latestnews h2{
    margin: 10px 5%;
    font-size: 1.3em;   
    width: 90%;
}
#latestnews ul, #latestnews li{
    text-align: center;
}
#latestnews li{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.latestnews img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#latestnews div.latestnews{
    float:none;
    width: 100%;
}
#latestnews p {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    clear: both;
}
#latestnews p.readmore{margin-top:10px; text-align:center;}



.column .sponsors {
    width: 100%;
}
.column {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.column .sponsors .b_250{
    border: none;
}
.b_250 img {
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
}
.b_250 iframe {
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
}
.sponsors {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
}
.sponsors h2{
    margin: 10px 5%;
    font-size: 1.3em;   
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
#sponsor-left {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
#sponsor-right {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}

}
```

Comment: do you want image to be center and auto responsive ?

Comment: I want there to be two columns of images in the 640px viewport and then for those images to be auto responsive.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the ads, add this(although I prefer to avoid using ID's in selectors):

```
#sponsor-left a > img { margin: 0 auto; }
```

At which point you can then increase the width of the images to 100% to fill the width you declared for the left and right columns.

Also as I noted in the comments remove the `float: right;` and change to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Doesn't work. I have the code still active in the page. It does the exact same thing as before.

Comment: I was assuming that would be enough specification for the stylesheet. I prefer not to use id's in CSS for speed reasons but use `#sponsor-left a > img` as the selector instead. Heres a screenshot showing it works: https://gyazo.com/e671bf1162fa6805f3cb773218ae83ee

Comment: I am still not sure if it worked, but how can I get the images width to expand? They still do nothing in terms of that.

Comment: Even after I do that, the left side doesn't respond when I expand the page. The right side does and always did..just not the left.

Comment: They should be scaling but only to 50% of the parent container or whatever value you set.

Comment: Theres a lot going on here. The .sponsor-right div is also getting pushed off screen because div.b_250 has a defined width of 305px which is larger than the 50% of sponsor left at smaller sizes.

Comment: Then what should I do? I am unsure of how to get this to work.

Comment: So remove that width of 305px and change #sponsor-right to display inline-block for starters.

Comment: Then add #sponsor-right a > img, #sponsor-left a > img { margin: 0 auto; } and you should arrive at this : https://gyazo.com/a224ed93cf20cbbc3c1744e7a1536112

Comment: Then I would personally increase the width of the left and right column to 48%. At which point you can target the images with #sponsor-right a > img, #sponsor-left a > img and increase the width.

Comment: So here, the left images are 80% of the parents 48%, and the right, 45% of the parents 48%.
https://gyazo.com/9b1f992591f86e8003ba98739bee87fe

Comment: Let me know if I lost you haha

Comment: It seems to definitely be helping, but the left side is still acting wacky.

Comment: So, you think that this section is creating the right side whitespace?

Comment: Did you also change the #sponsor-left to display:inline-block instead of float left?

Comment: div.sponsors has a margin right: https://gyazo.com/7dd7947f11c846fa3a160a488f88eadc

Comment: Yes, I did to both. `display:inline-block;` did not help for the left side. It actually pushed the one row down and looks weird now,

Comment: If you remove that, then change `.column .sponsors h2` to 
`margin: 0 auto 15px;`, you should get https://gyazo.com/f6d4d3816e483f6ea4a7e4985eed73a5

Comment: Ok hold up a second, let me see what changed when you made it inline-block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107811/discussion-between-paul-and-daniel-gomez).

Answer (score 0):

try `display:block max-width:100%; height:auto;`

**for image to be center**

You must use `display:block` or `display:inline-block` by default image is `display:inline`

**How to center?**

if your image is `display:block` use `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`

and for `display:inline-block` give `text-align:center` to image parent element

**Note**

Be care full  your image css does not have `float:left` or `float:right`

Comment: For the b_250 img div class?

Comment: put this css on that image you want to be auto responsive

Comment: @Paul do you want image to be 50% 50% with 10px margin ?